# How to test route with cxf endpoint consuming soap

Tags: apache-camel

I want to test a rout that consumes soap messages via a cxf endpoint. The service class is an annotated (@WebService) interface with one method that has 2 string parameters.

I want to test the route especially the handling of `MessageContentList` that is created by cxf.

But how to test such a route?
I see 2 options:

- replace the cxf endpoint by direct endpoint in test, but how to create a message contentlist that has the same shape as in real route?
- Use the real route and send a xml/soap message to it, but how to create such a method with the  interface that defines the soap message?

Are there other options?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use the real route and create a junit test (using CamelTestSupport) that uses the ProducerTemplate to send an exchange to your cxf endpoint?

```
public class MyTestClass extends CamelTestSupport {

    @Test
    public void myTestMethod() {
        Map<String, Object> headers = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        headers.put("content-type","application/xml");
        template.sendBodyAndHeaders("<real_cxf_endpoint_url>", "<test_xml_message>", headers);   
    }
}
```

See more info here: http://camel.apache.org/camel-test.html

Comment: the question is what type the exchange should have, how to create an exchange that is similar to a exchange that is sent in real (a xml soap message somehow converted to a "MessageContentList")
i don't have an example xml.

Comment: The above code WILL create an exchange similiar to an exchange that is sent in a real message.  If you want to manually create an exchange first however, use Exchange exchange = new DefaultExchange(new DefaultCamelContext()) Then you can set any headers/properties you need and use template.send(String URI, Exchange exchange) method override to call the web service.

Comment: Please select my answer and upvote it since it answers your original asked question.

Comment: "<test_xml_message>" this is not a message similar to real one! and i don't dont want to create it manually. If i change the classes specifying the interface the test will break.

Comment: You need to clarify your question then to state that.

Answer (score 0):

```
@EndpointInject(uri = "direct:source")
    protected Endpoint source;

@Produce
    protected ProducerTemplate producer;   
@Test
method() {
    Exchange response = createAndSendMessage();
}

private Exchange createAndSendMessage() {
    Exchange exchange = source.createExchange();
    exchange.getIn().setBody(contentlist);
    Exchange response = producer.send(source, exchange);
    return response;
}
```

If you want to use xml, create xml input file in resource folder and set it as exchange body.

```
exchange.getIn().setBody(requestXML);
```

Comment: the question is: how to setup a correct contentlist. meanwhile i just added instances of the types i defined with xsd. but i am not sure about ordering. i am accessing the items with get(i).

Comment: Import wsdl in SOAP UI, copy request xml from there

Comment: did someone read the question? I don't have an wsdl. It is code first. There is an annotated Javainterface. From this cxf generates an wsdl on the fly.